# How to automatically enable accessibility inspector in iOS simulator using Frank with Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, ios-simulator, frank

### The goal

I'm using Frank with Cucumber to test an app and my goal is to have it as automated as I can possibly get it. Part of that is turning back on the Accessibility Inspector after I reset the simulator.

### Details

To reset the simulator I use the step from the core_frank_steps.rb file (lines 258-260):

```
When /^I reset the simulator/ do
  simulator_reset_data
end
```

The Accessibility Inspector can be found in Settings > General > Accessibility, and is the only switch on that page in the simulator

### The question

Basically, is there a script or something I could write to have the Accessibility Inspector turned back on right after I reset the simulator? I'd prefer ruby, as all my other steps are written in ruby

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what purpose can Accessibility Inspector have in your automation but here is my answer.

Ruby cannot manipulate "iPhone Simulator" directly, every action (e.g. "Reset") is performed using Apple Script. Apple Script simulates user clicks on the menus.

For some examples, go to [Frank HostScripting module source](https://github.com/moredip/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/host_scripting.rb)

Modifying the menu indices in

```
def simulator_reset_data
  %x{osascript<<APPLESCRIPT
activate application "iPhone Simulator"
tell application "System Events"
  click menu item 5 of menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1 of process "#{Localize.t(:iphone_simulator)}"
  delay 0.5
  click button 2 of window 1 of process "#{Localize.t(:iphone_simulator)}"
end tell
  APPLESCRIPT} 
end
```

should give you the required result (the `delay` and the 2nd `click` line can be removed, they handle the "reset" confimation dialog).

Answer (score 0):

may be you use I18n to translate, you need copy I18n code to your localize.yml file
[enter link here to fix it](https://github.com/TestingWithFrank/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/localize.yml)